# group by in R dplyr for more than one variable on unique value of other variable

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have a dataset with three columns as below:

```
data <- data.frame(
   grpA = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
   idB = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6),
   valueC = c(10,10,20,20,10,30,40,50),
   otherD = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
)
```

`valueC` is unique to each unique value of `idB`.
I want to use `dplyr` pipe (as the rest of my code is in `dplyr`) and use `group_by` on `grpA`  to get a new column with sum of `valueC` values for each group.
The answer should be like:
`newCol <- c(40,40,40,40,40,120,120,120)`

but with `data %>% group_by(grpA) %>% 
mutate(newCol=sum(valueC)`, I get `newCol <- c(70,70,70,70,70,120,120,120)`

How do I include unique value of `idB`? Is there anything else I can use instead of `group_by` in `dplyr %>%` pipe.
I cant use `summarise` as I need to keep values in `otherD` intact for later use.
Other option I have is to create `newCol` separately through `sql` and then `merge` with `left join`. But I am looking for a better solution inline.
If it has been answered before, please refer me to the link as I could not find any relevant answer to this issue.

Comment: Why did you change your example?

Comment: Are u changing the expected output ?  First of all, please look at the `data`.

Comment: You should use `=` instead of `<-` when assigning values to a column name.

Comment: To emphasize  that why I need idB and sum(unique(valueC)) is not reliable

Comment: Could you please tell us how you got 40 for the first entry? (based on your example

Comment: It is not clear why the answer in `grpA` 1 is 40.

Comment: Also, BTW, there are 8 rows, and the expected showed only 6

Comment: as there are only three unique idB for grpA and I need to sum up corresponding valueC. Yes @akrun, you are right, there are 8 rows,  its just repeated value 40, I added that

Comment: I edited the post.  But, i think it is repeated value of 120.  Please check your example.  You have grpA 2 from 6 to 8

Comment: Yes edited, thanks@akrun. Just made up  this dummy example to look for solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `unique` with `match`

```
data %>% 
   group_by(grpA) %>% 
   mutate(ind = sum(valueC[match(unique(idB), idB)]))
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   grpA [2]
#   grpA   idB valueC otherD   ind
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     10      1    40
#2     1     1     10      2    40
#3     1     2     20      3    40
#4     1     2     20      4    40
#5     1     3     10      5    40
#6     2     4     30      6   120
#7     2     5     40      7   120
#8     2     6     50      8   120
```

---

Or another option is to get the `distinct` rows by 'grpA', 'idB', grouped by 'grpA', get the `sum` of 'valueC' and `left_join` with the original data

```
data %>% 
     distinct(grpA, idB, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
     group_by(grpA) %>%
     summarise(newCol = sum(valueC)) %>%
     left_join(data, ., by = 'grpA')
```